# Convert an object to string in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

For debugging purposes I would like to display the value of different objects. Is there any way you can convert an object to a string to display all of its properties and values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in a generic way. If you have an object that is set to a variable, like below:

```
Set(obj, { Name: "John Doe", Age: 33 })
```

Then you can use the [& operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/operators) or the [Concatenate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-concatenate) to create a string from that object:

```
Concatenate(
    obj.Name,
    " - ",
    obj.Age
)
```

You can also see the value of the variables in the View -> Variables menu on the ribbon.

If you believe that this is a feature that should be supported, consider creating a new item in the [PowerApps Ideas board](https://aka.ms/powerapps-ideas).

Comment: Thanks, will add request.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is the [JSON() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-json), which works like the JSON.stringify() function in JavaScript.

```
Set(obj, { Name: "John Doe", Age: 33 });
JSON(obj); // The stringified object.
```